# read a column containing a comma as single string in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i am trying to prase a csv file in my python code using scv.reader. It's working fine as expected but when it comes to a column containing a comma it converts that single column to multiple columns. My cvs looks like following.

```
1,Most Startups fail*,"Yes, most startups fail.","No, most startups succeed and provide big return to investors.",,,,,
```

Now i want "Yes, most startups fail." to be a single column but it converts it to two columns containing '"Yes' and 'most startups fail."' but i want a single cell containing "Yes, most startups fail.". How can i achieve this?. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code, it might help you:

```
import re
import csv

columnValue = input()
ouput = re.split('.""*', columnValue)  # doing split here

for i in ouput:
    print('\n', i)           # To show the output of text splited 

newfilePath = 'D:/Machine_Learning/General/ss.csv'  # the path location of CSV file to Write

# full code for writting column name as wanted 
with open(newfilePath, "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)    
    writer.writerow(ouput)
csvfile.close()
```

result screenshot:

[image]

Run this code with appropriate file path location for csv.

Comment: Please do not include code screenshots in your answers (and questions, too).